# Minecraft Server Not Accessible After Upgrading to Fiber Optic

Tags: windows-10, networking, port-forwarding

Just recently we were upgraded to fiber optic with our service provider optimum. We use an eero router, & so our network stayed pretty much the same.

Despite unlocking the port for the minecraft server on the firewall of the computer hosting the server, and port forwarding both IPV4 & IPV6 with the router software to that server computer, any external connections yield a simple 'Connection Refused: No further information Available'. This error differs from the device not existing, however, as if i put in something silly such as '120420' it yields the error 'Network is unreachable'. Pinging the server computer with its public ip address from my main desktop yield a reply. Additionally, I can connect to the minecraft server using the server computers local ip address (192.168.x.x).

Any thoughts?

Extra Info:

- The modem Optimum provided has a built in router function, but it should not be active unless it detects no other router down the line.
- We use a netgear eight port network switch.

Comment: Which ports have you forwarded?

Comment: How _does_ the modem detect another router down the line, I wonder... 1) Does your Eero router currently report that it has a public IPv4 address? 2) Does the server have a public IP address too? If it does, then why is there any port-forwarding still? 3) When someone from outside tries to connect, does Wireshark on your server show any packets to the Minecraft port? 4) When someone from the same LAN tries to connect to the server's IPv6 address, does that work? (The _server's_ IPv6 address, not the router's.)

Comment: To @harrymc ive only forwarded TCP/UDP In + Out Port 25565, but that should be all I need.

Comment: To @u1686_grawity Will try these when I get back, and will try to connect via IPV6 On the lan, could you elaborate on the first part with the modem and router as im not great with networking.

Comment: sounds a lot like CG-NAT - though that wouldn't be the case with IPv6 only IPv4

Comment: @u1686_grawity How would I go about checking wireshark for an attempted minecraft connection; I can connect via IPv6 to the MC server on my desktop but my friend on external wifi cannot?

Comment: @Waylon: Start a capture on the Ethernet interface, then enter `tcp.port == 25565` into the "Display filter" field.